# How in this code getting the count of substring?

Tags: c++

I was looking into a c++ code ,which counts occurrence of consecutive substr of size 2,link is [code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counts-distinct-consecutive-sub-string-length-two-using-c-stl/)

But i got some doubt regarding the line,

```
for (int i=0; i<str.size()-1; i++) 
        dPairs[make_pair(str[i], str[i+1])]++;
```

Here the dPairs is a map as follows,

```
map<pair<char,char>, int> dPairs;
```

What is the purpose of '++' in  "dPairs[make_pair(str[i], str[i+1])]++ " .

Comment: To actually count the bigram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dPairs[make_pair(str[i], str[i+1])]++;`

For the key `pair(str[i],str[i+1])` in map `dPairs`, the statement increments the value by 1.

For example, if the string is `aabaa`, as it loops, dPairs[pair<'a','a'>] will be incremented twice resulting in total count for substring `aa` as 2.

Answer (score 0):

The `++` is there to increment the count of substrings. A `map` holds unique keys, which the `[]` accesses, so if a key doesn't exist it's added, and if it does exist it's retrieved.

So let's say our string `str` is `"aaa"`. First we add `a, a` to the map, and the `++` will set its value to `1` (because it would default initialise to `0`). Then when we add the next value, first the previous `a, a` is retrieved, with the value of `1`, and it's value is incremented to 2.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::string str { "aaab" };
    std::map<std::pair<char, char>, size_t> pairs;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < str.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        pairs[std::make_pair(str[i], str[i+1])]++;
    }

    for (auto pair : pairs)
    {
        std::cout << pair.first.first << ", " << pair.first.second << ": " << pair.second << "\n";
    }

}
```

The `str` has 4 characters, so the are 3 iterations of the loop:

```
a, a = 1
a, a = 2
a, b = 1
```